# Project Euler 145 in C

Tags: c

I am giving the link to the question. Sorry for all the trouble.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler145

In the the above question, when n is 1000, the result is 120 which is correct but when n=948 the result is still 120 which is wrong.

```
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <math.h>
    int check(int n)
    {
       if(n%10==0)
       {
          return 0;
       }
       else
       {
          return 1;
       }
    }
    int rev(int n)
    {
       int s=0;
       while(n!=0)
       {
          s=s*10+n%10;
          n=n/10;
       }
   return s;
     }

  int count(int a)
  {
         int c=0;
         while(a!=0)
         {
              c++;
              a=a/10;
         }
         return c;
   }

   int odd(int k)
   {
          if(k%2!=0)
          {
             return 1;
          }
         else
          {
             return 0;
          }
    }

   int digit(int n,int p)
   {
         int k=0,c=0;
         while(n!=0)
         {
              k=n%10;
              if(odd(k)==1)
              {
                 c++;
              }
              n=n/10;
         }
         if(c==p)
         {
              return 1;
         }
         else
         {
              return 0;
         }
     }

     int result(int n)
      {
               int s=0,k=0,i=1,m=0,j=0;
               for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                      if(check(i)==1)
                      {
                          s=i+rev(i);
                          k=count(s);
                          m=digit(s,k);
                         if(m==1)
                         {

                              j++;
                          }
                      }
                 }
             return j;
            }



       int main()
       {
            int n=0,t=0,p=0,k=0,c=1,a[1000],i;
            scanf("%d",&t);
            for(i=0;i<t;i++)
            {
                 scanf("%d",&n);
                 a[i]=result(n);
             }
             for(i=0;i<t;i++)
             {
                 printf("\n %d",a[i]);
             }
      return 0;
    }
```

Please help me in solving the problem and as I am a complete newcomer in C
(I have been learning C for the last three weeks), my code is definately not the best code you will find on the net.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A good starting point would be to learn to indent your code consistently so that you and others can actually read it.

Comment: I'd recommend at least to put the problem here, not just refer to it in the title as "Project Euler 145"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your loop control here

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

So when `n` is 1000 you include `n`. But the question says ***below 1000***.

When you change that condition in the loop, the answer for `1000` is still `120`, but the answer for `948` becomes `119`, which is the correct answer.

It should be

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The program runs correctly. But when I upload the code in Hacker Rank, despite the output being correct it shows that it is wrong. Can you please help in resolving the problem

Comment: Try changing `printf("\n %d",j);` to `printf("%d\n",j);` without a space and the `newline` moved to its usual position.

Comment: Also change `scanf("%d \n",&t);` to `scanf("%d",&t);`

Comment: Explanations: In the `printf` your first output is a blank line which is not what the question is asking for nor does it ask for any `space`. *"output a single line containing a single integer"* so please read the conditions and instructions very carefully, always. In the `scanf` the format `%d` ignores leading whitespace, so don't confuse it with any attempt to make it ignore what it already does.

Comment: I have changed the code slightly. The compiler shows wrong answer despite 120 and 119 being displayed.

Comment: After your edit you are *still* using `printf("\n %d",a[i]);` which is not what the question asks for. You are still using `scanf("%d \n",&t);` too.

Comment: I have removed the first newline (when accepting t). The last one is required as it will otherwise print the output in the same line which the question is not asking for

Comment: Please read my comments again, more carefully and try exactly what I have recommended.

Comment: I printed the above code with a slight difference. But in checking the other test cases, it shows timeout. printf("%d\n",a[i]).

Comment: Look, the first thing that the `printf` does is to print a newline. So Hackerank sees an empty line. Then you output a space. Hacker says you should output an integer.

Comment: Of course it shows timeout. Your code is horribly inefficient. **That** is the real challenge, now you have solved the basic problem.